# CorePlot 1.3: setting space between axis and labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I need to position the y-axis according to the width of the labels, which is calculated dynamically. I have searched in the doc but I found nothing, even if it seems a pretty obvious thing to do. How do I accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I solved it with:

```
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft: padding];
```

Answer (score 0):

check the axis labeling policy,set the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic`

For Hint `yAxis.labelPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic`

For hint Please check [so Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904562/how-do-you-provide-labels-for-the-axis-of-a-core-plot-chart)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried this and it sets the padding to the whole graph, while i need to re-position only the x axis.

Comment: Sorry I explained myself badly, I have already placed the label correctly, but I need to set some extra space in the plot area before the y-axis (not the x-axis as I said above) to fit the labels.